# Graphics InvalidateRect, Buffers

Tags: graphics, buffer, invalidation

I just started learning Graphics at Univ. and I ran into a problem. We were told that we have to use a buffer to make the changes not visible to the user. What I don't understand is why we have to make `InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, FALSE);` the last parameter false(which I understood that it means that you will keep the elements drawn before - and it doesn't), in WM_MOUSEMOVE.

One more thing. I ran a simple example of drawing a rectangle by drag and drop and it seemed to be working fine before I added the buffer. I added the Buffer and before changing the param of InvalidateRect it would flash while I drag and dropped.

```
Imybrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(210, 210, 120));
        SelectObject(hdcBack, mybrush);
        mypen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(144, 1, 0));
        SelectObject(hdcBack, mypen);
        Rectangle(hdcBack, x1,y1,x2,y2);
```

Anyone can clear it out for me? Thanks

Comment: the last parameter to `InvalidateRect` is to specify whether you want to erase background within the updated area. The flashing is probably due to painting the buffer on every, even slightest, mouse move.

Comment: So If I use a buffer I cannot keep the content?

Comment: What content do you mean? I would assume that `before changing the param of InvaidateRect` means when it was `TRUE`. In that case you got background of your area being erased every time mouse position changed, hence the flickering. Actually, using a buffer should've solved the problem because you would be drawing in the buffer that is invisible to you at the moment of drawing, and then just substituting the updated view for the one currently displayed.